# ASP.Net Core with Google login: Cookie expiration does not work

Tags: c#, google-authentication

I have a ASP.Net Core MVC Web Application with SignalR. Login is with Google Authentication. I want the expire time about one year. The cookie will be set, but sometimes I have to login again. What could be the problem?

**Startup.cs**

```
var cookieExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(400);
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = cookieExpireTimeSpan;
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});

services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
    {
        googleOptions.CorrelationCookie.Expiration = cookieExpireTimeSpan;
        googleOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
        googleOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
});
```

**ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs**

```
var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: true, bypassTwoFactor : true);
```

**Cookie in Chrome**
[image: Cookie in Chrome]

Comment: Have you set your cookie to be persistent? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#persistent-cookies

Comment: yes, see my code in ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs

Comment: Oh true, didn’t see that, hmmm

Comment: There must be something else going on. Can you share your `ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs` ?